# Data Migration from Parse to back4App Error

Tags: parsing, data-migration, back4app

I just migration my App data from Parse to Back4App and followed the steps to set up back4App configuration. But now when I hit the Parse API with reference to back4App. It is continuously giving me following error: [Error]: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “files.parsetfss.com” which could put your confidential information at risk. (Code: 100, Version: 1.14.2) Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 1 after sleeping for 1.171176 seconds. Can anyone please provide a solution for this kind of error. I have updated Parse SDK in my App as well as ParseFacebook SDK.

Thanks in advance. 
Ratneshwar

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to PFFile object in parse, There is some issue in migrating parse to any other server.
I am also facing the issue and i have reported a bug on git forum of parse.
Here is the link:
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/2781

May be you should try by reporting your issue here.

Hope this helps!